# Infinite Scrolling in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, infinite, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to scroll the webpage till all the elements are loaded.
After a while my script gets failed.

I have tried to use different sleep time,
but after scrolling a while items takes too long and selenium reached
the bottom of the page.
I want to wait untill the next element are loaded.
here is my code

```
import time
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options


# Specify the path to the ChromeDriver executable
chrome_driver_path = r'C:\Users\ansar\edgedriver\msedgedriver.exe'

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options)
driver.maximize_window()
# Navigate to the desired webpage
url = 'https://www.bigbasket.com/ps/?q=rice'
driver.get(url)
# Approach 1

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 500);")
    time.sleep(0.5)

    #getting at the last of the page
    try:
        last = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="w-full text-black text-center mt-10"]').text
        if last == '- Thats all folks -':
            print('we reached end of the page')
            time.sleep(120)
            break
    except:
        pass


# Approach 2 
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 10

last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True: # Scroll down to bottom 
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
# Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

# Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: There is no error, the driver just get into bottom of webpage and infinitly scrolling at the bottom, but no new element is loading

Comment: maybe you should use `except Exception as ex: print(ex)` to see if you get some error.

Comment: or maybe you should scroll slower - like real human

Comment: on my old computer web page needs to load all images before it starts to add new elements - and sometimes it takes 1 min.

Comment: Yes I can defenitely increase the sleep time duration but i want to wait till next element are loaded. I want to use here webdriverwait but didn't know how can i use here. As if I wait untill the next element loaded by using xpath the class of the next element and  the element already loaded are same

Comment: maybe you should count elements to see if there are more elements than before. You may also try to use `JavaScript` to check page/window `height`